# Run Windows XP (32-bit) on Windows 7 (64-bit) on VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I think I have tried this before and failed.  I can't find anything on line which confirms or denies this.

Maybe I just did it wrong.  Anyone out there try this with success?  Or can anyone confirm this does not work?

Comment: what does not work? What's the error? We can't read  your mind.

Comment: I'm unsure as to what you mean by this? You can certainly run Windows XP 32bit as a virtual pc within Windows 7. As far as I know the host architecture doesn't affect the virtual pc's

Comment: @MaxMackie Well, mainly no, but you can't run a 64-bit virtual machine on a 32-bit computer. And I am pretty sure he means running Windows XP (32-bit) on Windows 7 (64-bit) on VirtualBox. Hence the title...

Comment: From the title, I gather the host machine is 64bit Windows 7 and he is making a VM with Windows XP 32bit. If I misread this, I apologize.

Comment: I got this setup and working! Thanks for the comments & answer. When i tried this at first I got an error with the USB 2.0 support. I tried again just now and everything looks okay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows XP (Home and Professional editions) will install and run under VirtualBox.org (versions 3 and 4, but you should try to use version 4 because it's faster) on Windows 7 (64-bit edition) without any problems.  I have a few clients doing this so that they can continue to support some old 16-bit applications that simply won't run in any edition of Windows 7 due to compatibility problems.

You can either use a real installation CD-ROM to install Windows XP (you'll need to configure the CD-ROM drive to pass-through to your VirtualBox session in the "Drives" configuration settings), or create a .ISO file of the installation CD (which is a good idea for backups anyway, and will result in a faster installation too) and mount that .ISO as a CD-ROM drive in VirtualBox ("Drives" configuration settings again).